# Deep link routing using branch.io iOS

Tags: ios, deep-linking, branch.io

When user receives a remote notification that someone started following them, user should be able to tap notification and get redirected to the profile page for that user that followed them. How can I use branch.io to achieve this? Must the notification payload contain the `userId` of the user who followed them so I know whose profile info to display?

Another use case would be if someone sent a chat message. Once they tap the remote notification they should be redirected to that specific chatroom. 
 I'm going through branch documentation and cant see anything addressing this.
Thanks for any assistance on right approach or relevant resources.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to enable user tracking to achieve this and the user_id of the follower needs to be input into the deep link that is sent in the notification of the person who was followed. Please see the below documentation on how to track users with in Branch:

https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/android/#track-users

Cheers,
Joie

Comment: Cant the `user_id` be included in the payload so I can parse it from `didRecieveRemoteNotification`? what do I need `branch` for with this approach?